# How to assign ether value at deployment of contract

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am trying to run this buyer seller contract in truffle using testrpc.
I am unable to assign the address and value for seller at the time of deploying contract. Here is my solidity code and deploy.js code

```
contract Purchase {
  uint public amount;
  address public seller;
  address public buyer;

  function Purchase(address addr, uint _amount) {
    seller = addr;
    amount = _amount;
  }

  function confirmPurchase(address _buyer, uint val) {
    buyer = _buyer;
    if ( val == amount) {
      buyer.transfer(amount);
      seller.transfer(this.balance);
      seller.balance;
    }
  }

  function getBalance() returns (uint balance) {
    return seller.balance;
  }

  function getAddr() returns (address) {
    return msg.sender;

  }
}
```

Deploy.js code:

```
var Purchase = artifacts.require("./Purchase.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
 deployer.deploy(Purchase,"0x13ac3e54b3d46757b6534e8b1c068caadb88da4a", 10);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Purchase {
  uint public amount;
  address public seller;
  address public buyer;

  event LogPurchase(address buyer, uint amount);

  function Purchase(uint _amount) {
    seller = msg.sender;
    amount = _amount;
  }

  function confirmPurchase() 
    payable // payable so it accepts value: from sender
    returns(bool success)
  { 
    if(msg.value != amount) throw; 
    LogPurchase(msg.sender,msg.value);
    seller.transfer(msg.value); // sends the funds to the seller
    return true;
  }
}
```

It's just a nudge to help unstuck you, not a fully viable solution you would rush into production.

When you deploy the contract, drop the address because it figures it out for you.

```
var Purchase = artifacts.require("./Purchase.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
 deployer.deploy(Purchase, 10);
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When we are deploying the contract with truffle in testrpc the contract must deploy in any of the 10 testrpc accounts which are available is that correct?

Comment: It will default to deployed from the first testrpc account and that account will be the owner.

Comment: But for me the contract deployed address is not matching with any of the given testrpc accounts

Comment: It is "from:" one of your accounts, but every contract has it's own unique address. It's not IN the user account, it's BY the user account.